# Conduct a linear hypothesis test on the estimated coefficients of a logistic regression in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I have the logistic regression of the form

[image: Y=f(X;\theta)=\alpha+\beta X]

where

[image: \theta={\alpha,\beta}]

The corresponding R code is the following.

`Regression_hat<-glm(Y~X,family=binomial(link='logit'))`

I know that in order to test the joint hypothesis test [image: H_{0}:\hat{\alpha}=0 \; \& \; \hat{\beta}=0]

the `linearHypothesis` test can be used with the following form:

`linearHypothesis(Regression_hat,c("(Intercept)=0","X=0"),test=c("F"))`

I would like to test (jointly) the hypothesis that both estimated parameters equal to two arbitrary values respectively. These two values are stored under different variable (e.g `V1` and `V2`) names in R although using variable names in the above code (`linearHypothesis(Regression_hat,c("(Intercept)=V1","X=V2"),test=c("F"))`) does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
linearHypothesis(Regression_hat, paste(c("(Intercept)", "X"), "=", c(V1, V2)), test = "F")
```

The issue is that writing, e.g., `"X=V2"` doesn't make `X2` look like a variable; it's just a part of this character. Using `paste` helps you to construct, e.g., `"X=3"` when `V1` takes value 3.